# Firebase-MLkit bar code scanner doesn't produce any results

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-mlkit

The app I have created has to recognise a bar code, more specifically a QR code, from an image. Research has dictated that it is best for me to use Firebase's ML-Kit to do this. I have followed the guide provided here https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/read-barcodes.

The issue however is is that the Barcode Detector never actually fails but instead the List of barcodes it returns is always empty and the size is 0. It doesn't matter if it is a valid QR code or a random picture. Not even if there are 2 or more QR codes in the image.

I have attempted to the solution described here: [Firebase- ML Kit library fails to detect barcode in Samsung J5 device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50692915/firebase-ml-kit-library-fails-to-detect-barcode-in-samsung-j5-device) and I have also checked various YouTube guides as well, to no success.

This is the code that scans an image for a barcode. The parameters are valid images because I also save those same images to the Pictures directory of the app, which does contain those images.

```
private void attemptToFindQRCode(byte[] imageBytes) throws CameraAccessException {

    Bitmap bitmapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.length, null);

    FirebaseVisionImage visionImage = FirebaseVisionImage.fromBitmap(bitmapImage);

    FirebaseVisionBarcodeDetector detector = setUpQRDetector();

    Task<List<FirebaseVisionBarcode>> result = detector.detectInImage(visionImage)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<List<FirebaseVisionBarcode>>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(List<FirebaseVisionBarcode> barcodes) {

                    processVisionBarcodeResult(barcodes);

                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@android.support.annotation.NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

}
```

I have thought that maybe it is to do with how I set up the barcode detector so this is the code for that:

```
private FirebaseVisionBarcodeDetector setUpQRDetector(){

    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);

    FirebaseVisionBarcodeDetectorOptions options =
            new FirebaseVisionBarcodeDetectorOptions.Builder()
            .setBarcodeFormats(FirebaseVisionBarcode.FORMAT_QR_CODE)
            .build();

    return FirebaseVision.getInstance().getVisionBarcodeDetector(options);

}
```

I have tried to remove the Options so that the detector will scan for any valid bar code but it still doesn't find anything.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I also receive no results from the scanner...

Comment: Same here, no failures but no results either

Comment: I don't know if this could help, I manage to get mine to work  and the problem was the metadata. the rotation and the size. I'm using fotoapparat and I did what is told in https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/read-barcodes#performance_tips. However, fotoapparat returns the rotation and the size(w,h) and for the format YV12 did the trick. That did it for me.

Comment: did you solved this?

Comment: @Dyan can you please post your finding as an answer?

Comment: I'm still having this problem with the unmodified example.  It looks to me like it has logic to handle rotation; and I don't see where you set the preview image format at all.